# Python while loop not executed until 'try'

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I got a very simple python while loop here:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        self.__main_thread.ask('wake',{})
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

The 'ask' function will not be executed until I change the code to the following:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        try:
            self.__main_thread.ask('wake',{})
        except:
            print(sys.exc_info())
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

This is a threading class, which I would like to do some jobs parallel with the main thread.

Here is the 'ask' and 'wake' function:

```
    def ask(self, action, arguments):
        if hasattr(self, action) and callable(getattr(self, action)):
            try:
                return getattr(self, action)(arguments)
            except:
                self.__exception_queue.put(sys.exc_inf())
        else:
            error = {'errCode':'ERR_00',"logMsg": "Invalid action: requested action '%s' is not implemented." % action}
            print (error)
            return error 


def wake(self):
    pic=None
    try:
        frame = self.webcam.read()[1]
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        pic = cv2.imencode('.png',frame)[1]
    except:
        if self.debug:
            print ('no picture available')
        raise
     else:
        self._photo_b64 = base64.encodestring(pic)
```

Basically, I am trying to read from my webcam periodically using a thread.
If I add the 'try' and 'except' to the 'run' function, the webcam image will be updated as expected, otherwise, no image is read from the webcam, and no exception raised.

Comment: what does `ask` do? Is it blocking for any reason?

Comment: What makes you say it's not being executed?

Comment: the 'ask' function check if  the required (asked) method is implemented by the object. If yes, call the method.

Comment: When the while loop executes normally, I got updated picture from my webcam. Othewise, I got nothing. That's how I know if the the while loop is executed.

Comment: Why don’t you add some `print`s inside the loop, so you see that it’s being executed.

Comment: I did add prints inside the loop! Specifically I add print in the 'wake' function, and it only prints with the 'try' statement added to the 'run' function